# Kinetic js photo image with blurred/transparent edges

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs, blur, blending

I'm building a photo-framing application using Kinetic JS (which is great, by the way).

I would like the photo, which starts life as a JPEG, to have blurred edges so it is blended in nicely to its patterned background.

Is there any native way using Kinetic or JS to blend in the edge borders (say 10 pixels) of a photo with its background?

Comment: http://kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.Filters.php you basically get 3 image filters, and blur-edges is not one of them. You would have to have the photo already blurred before you add it to the stage.

Answer (score 0):

kineticjs doesn't but you can use it in conjunction with other frameworks, try:

```
  http://creativejs.com/2011/12/day-5-blur-that-canvas/
```

Comment: so if you're alright with adding a layer for each image you want to blur, use this.